# Naming multiple plots with original name

Tags: r

I am plotting multiple plots:

```
a <- dir(pattern="stuff.*\\.txt$")
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  b <- read.table(a[i])
  jpeg(paste("/../.../", i, ".jpg"))
  plot(b$V1,b$V2, main=?)
  dev.off()
}
```

I want to name all jpg & main=? with original file name. All jpgs from this code are named from 1 to N. Is their any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but the variable `a[i]` is the original data file name. So you just need to do:

```
plot(b$V1, b$V2, main=a[i])
```

In your 'paste' function, the default separator is a space, so:

```
paste("A", "B")
```

gives `A B`. Instead, you want: `paste(`A`,`B`, sep="")`. When creating the jpeg file you should remove the `.txt` or `.csv` file extension from your data. So something like:

```
library(tools)
fname = file_path_sans_ext(a[i])
jpeg(paste("/../.../", fname, ".jpg", sep=""))
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks! That works for "main".
But not for jpeg(paste("/../.../", a[i], ".jpg")). Any ideas?

Comment: @user1286528 have you tried `collapse = ""` as `paste` argument? You could try getting the correct file name first, before you stick it into a loop.